# Having trouble with Matlab 'executeCypher' command

Tags: matlab, neo4j

I established connection with my Neo4j graph database:

```
neo4jconn = neo4j(url,username,password);
```

checked that  the connection is working:

```
neo4jconn.Message
ans =
     []
```

But when I try to query the database using Cypher:

```
query = 'MATCH(m:Nutrient) RETURN m';
results = executeCypher(neo4jconn, query)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error using database.neo4j.Neo4jConnect/executeCypher
Cannot execute Cypher(R) query.
```

When I use the same query command in Neo4j browser I get the result which I need.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the 'url' variable. When I start Neo4j it opens in the browser at: 'http://localhost:7474/browser/'. I created a new subdirectory /Neo4j/fiadb to store nodes/relationships of my database. And I used the following url for the Matlab 'neo4jconn = neo4j(url,username,password)' command:

```
url = 'http://localhost:7474/browser/fiadb'
```

This proved to be the right path:

```
neo4jconn.Message
```

ans =

```
 []
```